# Копировать файлы в папку Download Android

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. Не могу реализовать копирования файла с папки приложения "addons" в папку Download на устройстве. Возможно я не верно задаю пути? Или сам метод реализован неправильно? Помогите пожалуйста.

Пути:

```
File src = new File("src/main/res/addons/minecraft.mcworld");
File dst = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Download/minecraft.mcworld");
```

Кнопка копирования:

```
down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                copy(src, dst);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Метод:

```
    public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {



    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
        try {
            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1) файлы проекта упаковываются в APK и получить их как объект `File` нельзя. 2) файл должен лежать в правильной папке, читайте про `assets` (например [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/assets.php) - это наиболее подходит для произвольных файлов. 3) создать файл во внешней памяти тоже нельзя просто так - по вашему способу требуется сначала получить разрешение на доступ к ФС, но на Андроид 10 и новее это уже не работает - лучше сразу изучайте работу с файлами через [`SAF`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь